# How do I enable RDP in EC2 instances after mistakenly disabling rdp from Group Policy?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, group-policy

I mistakenly disabled RDP in one of my EC2 windows instances through Group Policy Editor. Now I cannot RDP to that instance even with administrator account. I get  [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRtdz.png) in the login screen now.

I did not enable WinRM in those instances, but not sure if they come enabled by default.

How can I re-enable RDP access in that EC2 instance?

Comment: Sounds like a tough problem.  I'd look at installing another windows machine on the same VPC and try to use administration tools on that new server to administer the other server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes, You can able to re-enable RDP using the **AWSSupport-ExecuteEC2Rescue Automation (AWS Systems Manager)**

**Please follow below steps carefully:**

1. Open the AWS Systems Manager console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose **Automation**.
3. Choose **Execute automation**.
4. In the documents list, choose **AWSSupport-ExecuteEC2Rescue**. The document owner is Amazon.
5. In the Document details section verify that Document version is set to the highest default version. For example, 13 (default).
6. In the Execution mode section, choose **Simple execution**. Leave the Targets and Rate Control option disabled.
7. In the Input parameters section, specify the following parameters:

   For UnreachableInstanceId, specify the **ID of the unreachable instance**.

   For LogDestination, specify an Amazon S3 bucket if you want to collect operating 
   system-level logs while troubleshooting your instance. Logs are automatically uploaded 
   to the specified bucket.

   For EC2RescueInstanceType, specify an instance type for the EC2Rescue instance. The 
   default instance type is t2.small.(Please leave as it is if you are confused and go 
   ahead)

   For SubnetId, specify a subnet in an existing VPC in the same availability zone as the 
   unreachable instance. By default, Systems Manager creates a new VPC, but you can 
   specify a subnet in an existing VPC if you want. (Please leave as it is if you are 
   confused and go ahead)

**Note**

If you don't see the option to specify a bucket or a subnet ID, verify that you are using the latest Default version of the document.

For Assume Role, if you created roles for this Automation by using the CloudFormation procedure described earlier in this topic, then specify the AssumeRole ARN that you copied from the CloudFormation console.

8. Choose Execute automation.

It takes sometimes (5-10 minutes) and you are able to access your old instance with new IP.

Here is the official AWS documentation for this issue:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connection-ec2-windows/